# How to configure files during build time with Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have some configuration files that need to be added to a container, with dynamic variables. Example:

```
#
# -= One of my app configuration files =- 
#

string SERVER = "127.0.0.1";
string LANG = "{dynamic_value}";
string OTHERVAR = "{other_dynamic_value}";
```

Would it be possible to have an external configuration file where all this variables are stored?

```
#
# -= My Docker centralised config file =- 
#

dynamic_value = "English";
other_dynamic_value = "North";
```

So the result file added to my container would be something like this:

```
#
# -= One of my app configuration files =- 
#

string SERVER = "127.0.0.1";
string LANG = "English";
string OTHERVAR = "North";
```

Thank you

Comment: Try to use env file

Comment: @Kilian Could you tell me a bit more? I don't really get it.

Comment: in my works I use ENV in Docker file or --e in the run command. And you can use them in your containers. You can verify with a "env" command in bash inside your container.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

You can use an env file or you can call them on launch of the container with the below.

-e var='value'

Answer (score 1):

Create a script file in the scripting language of your choice e.g. ruby.

```
require 'json'
myconfigfile = 'config1.json'
j= ''
File.open(myconfigfile, "r") do |f|
  j = JSON.parse(f.read)
end

File.open('appconfig.txt','w') do |f|
  f.write 'string SERVER = "127.0.0.1"' + "\n"
  f.write 'string LANG = ' + j['dynamic_value'].to_s + "\n"
  f.write 'string OTHERVAR = ' + j['other_dynamic_value'].to_s + "\n"
end

`docker build .`
```

In this sample I have assumed that your centralized config file is in json format.

```
{
  "dynamic_value" : "English",
  "other_dynamic_value" : "North"
}
```

In the Dockerfile, copy the appconfig.txt file so created into your container.